# Positioning in CSS, when scaling the webpage the text & background shifts

Tags: html, css, positioning

When minimized and scaled to different positions some the text and background shift to different spots making text shift off the screen or on top of other text or links.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gamepage {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-size: 100%;
}


/* tabbar */

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("https://www.waukeepubliclibrary.org/sites/default/files/Event%20Images/Teen%20Events/MurderMystery_TopBanner-1024x265.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 2;
}

#home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-style: groove;
}

#how2play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 47px;
  border-style: groove;
}

#character {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 137px;
  border-style: groove;
}


/* link format */

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* background */

.background {
  positon: absolute;
  background: url("https://imagevars.gulfnews.com/2021/07/05/shutterstock_1016099710-1625487358677_17a7698bad7_large.jpg") no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 72px;
  left: 8px;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

#title {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Courier New;
}

#text {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 125px;
  left: 25px;
}

#playbutton {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 360px;
  left: 660px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
  border: 5px;
  border-style: double;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gamepage">
    <div class="header">
      <div id="home">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div id="how2play">
        <a href="how2play.html">How to Play</a>
      </div>
      <div id="character">
        <a href="characterlist.html">Character List</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background">
      <div id="title">Murder Mystery</div>
      <div id="text">Find the murderer, before it's too late...</div>
      <a href="homepage/thegame1.html">
        <div id="playbutton">Play Now</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**I've Tried**

- Changing all values to %'s
- Changing all the values using `vh` and `vw`.
  **This fixed some of the problem but not all**
- Played around with the absolute and relative positioning/adding div parent tags

All this is very new to me so there might be a simple solution I don't know of

Comment: Can you go into more detail with your errors and how you'd like it to look

Comment: Dont use position:absolute... maybe this can be the issue

Comment: Yes position absolute is definitely an issue, modern grid & flexbox should be used instead

Comment: Perhaps describe in some detail what your desired output/display should look like; something like: "Position all the buttons in the top in a single row; What I have in class "background" is the body of the page; when I view this on small screens I want "xxxx" when I view this on large screens I want "yyyy" etc

Comment: @ZachJensz if you open the code in full screen, then minimize the page things will shift around I want when minimize the text scales down with the webpage

Comment: What should occur if the text you see is too wide for the screen? should the header by sticky at the top and always visible? What should happen when the screen is too small in width for the header links/buttons?  I suspect you do not mean to scale down to super tiny size text and images just to fit it all on a very small device...

Comment: @ZachJensz when branching off using this code how would I go about positioning the text to assigned spots on the page, would it be just position: relative and assign the position using top and left or should I read up on "flex" to position as I've never used that before

Comment: @J.Meyer For positioning items along a line look into flexbox. For positioning elements inside a grid look into CSS grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML and CSS should look something like the example below.

Here I have swapped out your IDs for semantic HTML elements, and absolute positioned elements for modern flexbox/grid

Look into flexbox and grid for single axis and dual axis positioning

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30% 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

header {
  background: url("https://www.waukeepubliclibrary.org/sites/default/files/Event%20Images/Teen%20Events/MurderMystery_TopBanner-1024x265.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  min-height: 10vh;
  list-style: none;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  display: inline-block; /* Allows for padding and your rotation of [Play Now] */
  color: inherit;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  background: #000b;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

main {
  background: url("https://imagevars.gulfnews.com/2021/07/05/shutterstock_1016099710-1625487358677_17a7698bad7_large.jpg") no-repeat;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-family: Courier New;
}

.playbutton {
  color: black;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
  border: 5px;
  border-style: double;
}
```

```html
<!-- Use semantic HTML instead of divs with IDs -->
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="how2play.html">How to Play</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="characterlist.html">Character List</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>Murder Mystery</h1>
  <p id="text">Find the murderer, before it's too late...</p>
  <a href="homepage/thegame1.html" class="playbutton">Play Now</a>
</main>
```